# Can Google App Engine projection query return entity keys?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I have:

```
class Like(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User,collection_name='likes')
    photo = db.ReferenceProperty(Photo,collection_name='likes_received')
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Is it possible to run a projection query that returns only a list of photo keys?

```
photos = db.GqlQuery("SELECT photo FROM Like WHERE created < DATETIME(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)").fetch(10)
```

The code above produces:

```
BadValueError: Unsupported data type (<class 'models.Photo'>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, my first answer was wrong.  There is a real problem with projection queries -- ReferenceProperty is not (yet) supported.  Alfred is looking into this; since the 1.6.6 prerelease SDK went out today and this was already present in the 1.6.5 SDk I doubt we'll get this fixed in 1.6.6 but 1.6.7 is a possibility.

As workarounds, you could use db.ListProperty(db.Key), which is a list of keys (you'd store only one key), or a StringProperty whose value is the str() of the key.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the info and the suggested workarounds!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Photo class hasn't been imported yet.

Comment: could you please provide a bit more info as to how to get this working? I've tried pretty much every permutation I could think of and specifying a ReferenceProperty in a projection query consistently fails. The exact same code works when using any other property allowed in projection queries (docs referenced: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection)

Comment: Photo class has been imported, it is being used elsewhere within the file. I am generally observing the same behaviour as @Sologoub. Only tested in SDK, not sure if it happens in production too.

Comment: Hm. Looks like projection queries for reference properties are not supported. Let me ask around.